# HTML/PHP/SQL - Matching Values From Database To Website

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on a website which features a payment plan, with a different price per plan. With this, I've created a database with SQL so if needed, I can change the price of a plan, so it automatically updates onto the website.

Using an example given on W3Schools, I've created a base file that should grab the product name and price. However, since there are three different plan types,  I'm not sure how to define (in index.php) each product and price. Each product has a primary key, which I've not added into the PHP file, so if anyone could give me any advice on how to approach this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The idea is to change a line such as

```
<p class="plan-price">&pound;14.95 <span>
```

Into something like

```
<p class="plan-price">&pound;'.$SESSION_PRICE['price'].' <span>
```

price.inc.php

```
<?php
include '../dbh.php';

$sql2    = "SELECT * FROM products";
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $_SESSION_PRICE['productTitle'] = $row['productTitle'];
        $_SESSION_PRICE['price'] = $row['price'];
    }   
}
?>
```

index.php (Just the required section)

```
<section class="section-plans">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Order Today.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="plan-box">
                <div>
                    <h4>Premium</h4>
                    <p class="plan-price">&pound;14.95 <span> / Month </span></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Priority Acccess</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>24/7 Online Support</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Access Anywhere</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Unlimited Speed</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-full">Sign Up Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="plan-box">
                <div>
                    <h4>Pro</h4>
                    <p class="plan-price">&pound;9.95 <span> / Month </span></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Worldwide Access</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>24/7 Online Support</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Access Anywhere</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-close-circled  icon-small"></i>Unlimited Speed</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost">Sign Up Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <div class="plan-box">
                <div>
                    <h4>Lite</h4>
                    <p class="plan-price">&pound;4.95 <span> / Month </span></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Worldwide Access</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>24/7 Online Support</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-close-circled icon-small"></i>Access Anywhere</li>
                        <li><i class="ion-close-circled  icon-small"></i>Unlimited Speed</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-ghost">Sign Up Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you should name a variable $_SESSION_PRICE, as that looks like it should be a superglobal. Maybe try something like this:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $session_price['productTitle'] = $row['productTitle'];
        $session_price['price'] = $row['price'];
    }   
}
```

Then, in order to get that PHP value into your HTML, echo it out in a PHP block. Try this:

```
<p class="plan-price">&pound; <?php echo $session_price['price']; ?><span>
```

You will need to include the price.inc.php file in your index.php file in order to have access to the variables that were created in there. So somewhere before you need the variables have a statement like this:

```
include 'price.inc.php';
```

Now, the problem with all of that will be that you are looping throw the returned results from your SQL query and repeatedly assigning over the same index:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $session_price['productTitle'] = $row['productTitle'];
        $session_price['price'] = $row['price'];
}
```

If you are fetching MULTIPLE products, you will need to store them like so:

***EDITED WHILE LOOP***

```
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $session_price[$i]['productTitle'] = $row['productTitle'];
  $session_price[$i++]['price'] = $row['price'];
}
```

Then, you would need to dynamically create the HTML to display EACH product in a loop, like this:

```
<?php 

  foreach ($session_price as $individual_item) {
    $item_name = $individual_item['productTitle'];
    $price = $individual_item['price'];
?>

  <div class="col span-1-of-3">
    <div class="plan-box">
        <div>
          <h4><?php echo $item_name; ?> </h4>
          <p class="plan-price">&pound;<?php echo $price; ?><span> / Month </span></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <ul>

              <?php 

                if ($individual_item['productTitle'] == 'Premium') {
                  $access = 'Priority Access';
                } else {
                  $access = 'Worldwide Access';
                }

              ?>

                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i><?php echo $access; ?></li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>24/7 Online Support</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Access Anywhere</li>
                <li><i class="ion-ios-checkmark icon-small"></i>Unlimited Speed</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-full">Sign Up Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php 

} // end foreach loop

?>
```

Comment: Okay great, I can get the first price to display correctly at £14.95. However, how would I display the prices for the other two, as I'll just be referencing the same price over and over?

Comment: See my edit, it covers handling the multiple products.

Comment: Just given it a go and it's throwing a warning for "Illegal string offset..." and then mentions productTitle and price

Comment: That's because I forgot to include an index counter in the while loop, check it now with the adjusted while loop that has the $i counter. Let me know if you need me to explain that portion I'd be happy to.

Comment: It's now throwing an error on line 80 of index.php "Undefined variable: session_price" which is 'foreach ($session_price as $individual_item)'. But surely it can access it because I've included price.inc.php into my index file, so I'm not sure why that is being thrown

Comment: Problem solved, thank you so much for you help, completely works now! :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

your

`<p class="plan-price">&pound;'.$SESSION_PRICE['price'].' <span>`

should add echo

`<p class="plan-price">&pound;<?php echo $SESSION_PRICE['price'] ?> <span>`